# Detect Jenkins build abort event

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to detect Jenkins build abort event in Builder plugin and perform graceful process finalization?

This is the only information I was able to find: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) is thrown on job abort, so by catching it, it is possible to detect and handle job termination.

More detailed information can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/dfe9604cb907523f4a2f).

Comment: Where should i handle this exception? In Class which implements ISuiteListener? or in testcases ?

Comment: @BrijeshSoni In my case, it was in the Builder.perform method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post-build task plugin:-

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task

Use this plugin to grep when is the build aborted.
Add the search message and then run your clean-up script (shell script also works here.)

For more info about aborting build in Jenkins ,click [here](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/dfe9604cb907523f4a2f)

Also [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17116) might be useful