# Short Note while aborting a build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is it possible to add a Short note while aborting a build **manually** in Jenkins? it is possible in Teamcity but i dont see any option in Jenkins.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065516/detect-jenkins-build-abort-event

Comment: @user7294900 thanks for the suggestion but am looking for adding a note **manually** while aborting a build due to some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Go the build url (eg myjenkins.com/myjob/1), and hit the "Edit Build Information" button on the left of side of the page. That will let you edit the build name and description.